# BusyIndicator BusyContent bind to property in WPF window wont update

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created an WPF form which includes the BusyIndicator from Extended WPF Toolkit. This window runs on new thread and implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Next, I bind the BusyContent to the Property which shows fine on BusyContent but seems not updating. Any Ideas ?

```
 <StackPanel>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True" BusyContent="{Binding BusyText, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
</StackPanel>

 private string _busyText;
    public string BusyText
    {
        get
        {
            return _busyText;
        }
        set
        {
            _busyText = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("BusyText");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is whether you block the UI thread.

Comment: WPF uses "Windows" not Forms...

Comment: I don't block the UI since the property changes on specific intervals.

Comment: @Jim: That does not mean anything, i can have a busy loop that changes the property in fixed intervals, it would still block the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the solution with background Thread and it started working:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        BusyText = ReceivedMessage;
    };
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
{
    _busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
};
_busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```